# Sum of random variates and convolution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I'm currently working through Allen Downey's book [Think Stats](http://greenteapress.com/thinkstats/). On page 74 of the PDF version problem 6.8 asks:

*Suppose I draw two values from a distribution; what is the
distribution of the larger value? Express your answer in terms of the PDF
or CDF of the distribution.*

I have trouble understanding what this problem is asking, and I'd greatly appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: The trouble might come from not knowing the definitions of "PDF", "CDF" and "distribution". Do you?

Answer (score 1):

First, as @Did said, if you don't know what a distribution, PDF and CDF are, you have a more fundamental gap in your statistical understanding that should be addressed, either by remedial reading, or by talking to your professor/TA if you have one.

That being said, assuming independent draws, it is asking you to determine two quantities:

1. $P(\max{(X_2,X_1)}\leq x)$
2. The derivative of (1), per the definition of a PDF

For CDF:

Think about what it means for the maximum of two values to be below a certain number, $x$. For that to happen, you need to have both numbers fall below $x$, and so for each choice of $x$ you essentially have a binomial experiment (coin flipping), where the probability of heads is determined by the underlying distribution $P(X\leq x)$.

In this case, you want to know what is the probability of two heads for independent tosses, so you get $P(\max{(X_2,X_1)}\leq x) = \{P(X\leq x)\}^2$

For PDF: A PDF is the rate of increase of the cumulative probability function, or CDF. So you take the derivative of the CDF to get your answer. I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking you to find the distribution of $\max(X_1,X_2)$, where $X_1$, and $X_2$ are values from the distribution.